# Insert statement into custom WordPress database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I have a custom database that I want to insert items into from a WordPress front-end interface. When I submit the form, I can get the JSON values just fine, but for some reason, it doesn't seem to be inserting into the database. I do not get any error messages.

Here's what I'm doing (please note that I am testing the `name` variable, hence why it's not pulling from an input field):

I am using the `auto_increment_id` value from `SHOW TABLE STATUS` to create the `commmittee_id` value, and would prefer for that to be inserted as the primary key.

**JavaScript**

```
$(".addButton").click(function() {
    var commitAddID = $(this).attr('id');
    var name = "1name";
    var date_created = $("#addCommCreated_input_"+commitAddID).val();
    var status = $("#addCommStatus_input_"+commitAddID).val();
    var disbanded = $("#addCommDisbanded_input_"+commitAddID).val();

    var dataString = {
     'action': 'addCommittee',
     'committee_id': commitAddID,
     'old_id': commitAddID,
     'name': name,
     'description': '',
     'date_created': date_created,
     'status': status,
     'disbanded': disbanded
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
      url: addCommittee.ajaxurl,
      type: "POST",
      data: dataString,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
        $("#name_"+commitAddID).html(name);
        $("#created_"+commitAddID).html(date_created);
        $("#status_"+commitAddID).html(status);
        $("#disbanded_"+commitAddID).html(disbanded);
      }
    });
```

**functions.php**

```
  // set up AJAX call for addCommittee
add_action('wp_ajax_addCommittee', 'addCommittee');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_addCommittee', 'addCommittee');

function addCommittee() {
  global $wpdb;

  $committee_id = esc_sql($_POST['committee_id']);
  $old_id = esc_sql($_POST['old_id']);
  $name = esc_sql($_POST['name']);
  $created = esc_sql($_POST['date_created']);
  $status = esc_sql($_POST['status']);
  $disbanded = esc_sql($_POST['disbanded']);
  $desc= esc_sql($_POST['description']);


  $wpdb->insert('wp_bubu_committees',
              array(
              'old_id' => '',
              'name' => $name,
              'description' => '',
              'date_created' => $created,
              'status' => $status,
              'disbanded' => $disbanded
              )
            );
            exit();
  }
```

I have also localized the AJAX URL in `functions.php`. Any ideas?

Edit: Updated the code-- the action was set to the . I now am able to insert into the database, but it only allows me to insert one item. Attempting to insert additional items returns nothing, but the data does post to JSON.

Comment: Is Committee id primary key?

Comment: Committee_id is the primary key. I'm getting that value from the `auto_increment_id` that you get from `SHOW TABLE STATUS`

Comment: Add this   'committee_id' => $id  first array and remove the second and third array in inser

Comment: Remove the committee I'd in query and try

Comment: Didn't work-- do you mind moving this conversation to chat? I can provide more information about the code

Comment: Yes. I don't mind

Comment: Sorry, can you create the room? Not sure how... first time!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129392/discussion-between-vel-and-sleepy-daze).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the data type json.

```
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        url: addCommittee.ajaxurl, 
        type: "POST", 
        data: dataString, 
        success: function (response) { 
            $("#name_"+commitAddID).html(name); 
            $("#created_"+commitAddID).html(date_created); 
            $("#status_"+commitAddID).html(status); 
            $("#disbanded_"+commitAddID).html(disbanded); 
            alert(response); 
        } 
    });
```

Comment: Didn't work. The `alert(response)` seems to print either nothing or a blank, regardless if I'm doing `alert();` or `console.log();` Interestingly enough, as I'm testing these inserts, the committee_id is increasing by 2 each time. Not sure why it's going up by 2, but it seems to me that it's processing the new auto_increment_id. Just not posting it to the DB.

Comment: So what I needed to do was make sure that `'old_id' =>` was being set to something. I set it to it's variable, $old_id. After that and after removing the `dataType: json`, I was able to start adding more than one. Thanks for all your help, @vel!

Comment: @sleepy_daze, happy to help you.